# ActiveMQ java client startup hangs when server is unavailable

Tags: java, activemq-classic, ultraesb

I'm trying to implement a monitoring service for an ActiveMQ server. There I have implemented a polling service to connect to the ActiveMQ server periodically and do a queue browse operation to do a health check on ActiveMQ Server.

Here is the code snippet that I use to start the connection.

```
ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(amqUrl);
connectionFactory.setTrustStore(amqSslTrustStorePath);
connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword(amqSslTrustStorePasswd);
connectionFactory.setKeyStore(amqSslKeyStorePath);
connectionFactory.setKeyStorePassword(amqSslKeyStorePasswd);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(amqUser, amqPasswd);
connection.start();
```

The issue is when the server is unavailable the `connection.start()` call hangs without throwing an error. For the monitoring purpose I need to detect this.

Am I doing anything wrong here or is there any better way to do this?

**UPDATE:** This happens only when I use a failover based ActiveMQ url (eg: `failover:(ssl://192.168.1.112:61617,ssl://192.168.1.112:61619)?randomize=false` otherwise it does work as expected, that is it throws a JMSException (eg: `ssl://192.168.1.112:61617`)

Comment: your url is based on failover ?

Comment: yes it is. `failover:(ssl://192.168.1.112:61617,ssl://192.168.1.112:61619)?randomize=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for failover transport :

> `maxReconnectAttempts`: Default Value = -1 | 0
>
> **From ActiveMQ 5.6**: default is
>   -1, retry forever. 0 means disables re-connection, e.g: just try to connect once. **Before ActiveMQ 5.6**: default is 0, retry forever.  All
>   ActiveMQ versions: a value >0 denotes the maximum number of reconnect
>   attempts before an error is sent back to the client.